How can I check a looker dashboard has finished loading completely?
I'm developing looker dashboards and to test performance I need to programmatically check when a dashboard has finished loading.
This very old repo makes use of this method window.awaitPerformanceObservation("rendered") https://github.com/looker-open-source/looker-load-testing
That method works in the Chrome console but trying to use it with selenium the way that repo does here does not work: https://github.com/looker-open-source/looker-load-testing/blob/6c05299a01b5e432eaf83b1105a5bdc69047b078/locust_test_scripts/default_dashboard_loadtest.py#L42.
def open_dashboard(self):
    script = """
    window.awaitPerformanceObservation("rendered").then(function() {
        var dash_render = document.createElement("div");
        dash_render.id = "dash_listener";
        document.body.appendChild(dash_render);
    });"""

    try:
        self.client.get(f"{SITE}/embed/dashboards/{str(DASH_ID)}")
        self.client.execute_script(script)
        self.client.wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.ID, "dash_listener")
            )
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        print("hit timeout")

It doesn't ever seem to fire and selenium waits forever checking for that dash_listener element it should have created.
I can find zero docs on this window.awaitPerformanceObservation("rendered") thing. Is it still valid? What events/elements/etc can I check to confirm a looker dashboard has fully loaded all its tiles?

Hi there -- did you ever find a decent way to measure Looker dashboard load times systematically? .... I thought GA and/ or Adobe analytics tags might also roughly measure this, but perhaps not. Looking to achieve the same thing, albeit in AWS (we self-host Looker for some reason)

I haven't had time to reach out to google, but I think they are the only ones that can answer this. There is zero documentation and this repo is technically unofficial so these magic, totally undocumented, functions could be implementation details. Pretty crappy, pretty annoying.

Looker and Looker Studio (formerly Google Data Studio) are quite different, and the question is tagged with both (though the text indicates the questioner is looking for an answer related to Looker, not Looker Studio).
For Looker, the best answer is likely to leverage the dashboard:run:complete JavaScript event:

This event is created when a dashboard has finished running and all tiles have finished loading and querying. This event is created whether or not all tiles load successfully.

The parent page attaches a listener for that event to the Looker report embed iframe, and then Selenium should be able to wait on that condition. The following (untested) code might serve as a starting point:
driver.executeScript(
  """
  window.__loaded__ = false;
  window.addEventListener("dashboard:run:complete", function(event) {
    if (event.origin === "https://instance_name.looker.com") {
      window.__loaded__ = true;
    }
  });
  """.trimIndent()
)

wait.until {
  (it as JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("return window.__loaded__") == "true"
}

For Looker Studio (Google Data Studio) reports, I've found the following condition seems to work well:
wait.until(
  ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//div[@id='body' and contains(@class, 'page-rendered')]")
  )
)

